# How to add action button to RNFIREBASE MESSAGING notifications

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I explored this github issue: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1811

But found no answer because, `react-native-firebase` package is no longer maintained. Rather, it has been divided into particular packages. I found no option to add Action Buttons to a Notification using `@react-native-firebase/messaging`

I raised storm in internet but found no solution for it. Please show me a path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved in the following way:
I used `react-native-push-notifications` library. Whenever a new message is received, a new notification is created. Adding action buttons is easy with the library.